# OBIEE how to modify analysis table

Tags: obiee

I have an analyis pivot table

[image]

and here is the result

[image]

Is there any way to modidify this analysis pivot table to be like this:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Please see the above image.

- Create the sum in criteria itself.
- In column labels click on that summation and select none.
- Create a dummy column having string 'Total', and arrange everything like below image.

Comment: Also u can edit the column headings in criteria only as per your requirement.

Comment: very nice answer :)